# Does std::stringstream has two buffers and hence two markers?

Tags: c++, fstream, stringstream

On C++ primer chapter 17; I/O streams; it is said that an object of type `std::iostream` or a derived type like `std::fstream`, `std::stringstream` support both reading and writing. Also these types have only one Marker and a single Buffer:

> The `fstream` and `stringstream` types can read and write the same stream. In these types there is a single buffer that holds data to be read and written and a single marker denoting the current position in the buffer. The library maps both the `g` and `p` positions to this single marker.

So to understand more I've done this program:

```
int main(){


    std::fstream fio("data.txt");
    std::cout << fio.tellg() << '\t' << fio.tellp() << '\n';
    fio.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    std::cout << fio.tellg() << '\t' << fio.tellp() << '\n';

    std::stringstream ss("abcd\nefg\nhi\nj");
    std::cout << ss.tellg() << '\t' << ss.tellp() << '\n';
    ss.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    std::cout << ss.tellg() << '\t' << ss.tellp() << '\n';

}
```

The output:

```
 0      0
 14     14
 0      0
 13     0
```

- As you can see when using `std::fstream` if I move the read marker using `seekg()` then the `tellg` and `tellp` return the same value. Which is so logical.
- However when moving the read marker for `std::stringstream`, `tellg` and `tellp` return different value so the write marker hasn't been moved?
- Does this mean `std::stringstream` has two buffers and two markers? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the book is wrong.

It is [std::basic_filebuf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf) which synchronizes read and write positions, and,

> the class template **basic_fstream** implements high-level input/output operations on file based streams. It interfaces a file-based streambuffer (**std::basic_filebuf**) with the high-level interface of (std::basic_iostream).

The base class however, [std::basic_streambuf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf), does maintain separate input and output buffers. Note that

> the I/O stream objects std::basic_istream and std::basic_ostream, as well as all objects derived from them (std::ofstream, **std::stringstream**, etc), are implemented entirely in terms of **std::basic_streambuf**.